# How to add LIMIT clause in postgressql Query?

Tags: postgresql

I want to add LIMIT clause in postgressql query but its give me error

```
SELECT complaint_id FROM complaint_details_v2 a where a.road_dept SIMILAR TO 'PWDBnR' order by a.server_time desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

Below is the error:

```
ERROR: LIMIT #,# syntax is not supported
SQL state: 42601
Hint: Use separate LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.
Character: 87
```

Answer (score 4):

For the example above - skip the '0,' bit

```
SELECT complaint_id FROM complaint_details_v2 a where a.road_dept SIMILAR TO 
'PWDBnR' order by a.server_time desc LIMIT 10
```

LIMIT 0, 10 is not postgres dialect, use OFFSET. For example if you want to next 10 results:

```
SELECT complaint_id FROM complaint_details_v2 a where a.road_dept SIMILAR TO 
'PWDBnR' order by a.server_time desc OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10
```

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/limit_offset

Answer (score 0):

Query should be for selecting first 10 rows

```
SELECT complaint_id FROM complaint_details_v2 a where a.road_dept SIMILAR TO 'PWDBnR' order by a.server_time desc LIMIT 10
```

If you want to select x rows after y records(start count from 0), You should use

```
SELECT complaint_id FROM complaint_details_v2 a where a.road_dept SIMILAR TO 'PWDBnR' order by a.server_time desc LIMIT x OFFSET y
```

Hope this helps!